# HTML5 web audio seekTo for buffered source

Tags: html, audio, web-audio-api

I have web application(similar to Karaoke) where user can record his voice over instrumental.
After recording user plays back recording. Here I play instrumental in `<audio>` tag and voice using web audio api. To sync both audios on play/pause I calculate time like this

```
pausedAt = Date.now() - startedAt;
startedAt = Date.now() - pausedAt;
```

This works fine. Issue is when user uses slider on audio tag to move forward/backward. I am thinking of solution like this

- Use `ontimeupdate` event, stop the voice and then use `startAt(currentTime)` where currentTime is of instrumental playing in audio tag.

Since there is no seekTo function in api, I have to stop and then start audio. Is there any better solution for this?

Second issue I face is seeking on audio tag is not smooth. If I arbitrarily clicks on progress bar sometimes it doesn't work. When I saw network tab in developer tool window I saw something like shown in image. It sends out some 600 requests and some 86 MB data downloaded whereas file size is less than 10 MB.
[image]

Comment: For all complex audio manipulation (read: everything besides play/stop) it is recommended to user Web Audio API which gives you more explicit and well-standardized controls over audio playback: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Comment: So you mean that you want the recorded audio to save at the same time the audio element plays? Like when recording from 0.00 to 0.10, and then scroll to 0.36, it places something like silence from 0.10 to 0.36 in the recording file? That will be hard to do as recording is done with buffers... Although you might have a 1 second no sound audio file, and then add that to the buffer as many times as you want. For the loading, it seems like you are constantly reloading the request... Do you have a piece of code that does load that file?

Comment: ... so what I think, is that some code reloads the file everytime you click on the element or something like that, but I do need to see your code to find out what is wrong.

Comment: @MarijnS95 No, during recording user won't be doing any seek. Once recording is over, I get recorder buffer using recorder.js's function getBufferCallback. Then I use that buffer to play back along with instrumental. I don't want to provide 2 audio controls for user to manage. So I just bind instrumental to audio control and recorded voice is played in background.

Comment: I still remember from when using the api (before I found out that `createMediaElementSource` existed), a buffer could only be played once. When calling stop on the source node(the node which plays your buffer) you can't restart it. See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioBufferSourceNode). I recommend you to find some way to put the source inside an Audio element. You can easily control those with currentTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use the Web Audio API to do this.   will never give you precise synchronization, and it will rely on streaming to seek - which is going to result in extra downloading, as you saw.  Just load the song via XHR and decodeAudioData, and provide your own playback controls.

Comment: Can you please point me to any existing samples over internet doing similar? I am confident of loading song via XHR with volume control but not sure about progress bar with seeking feature?

Comment: @pramodtech When you play your `AudioBufferSourceNode`, there is an `offset` argument to denote where in the buffer you should start playing from:

http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioBufferSourceNode